# date column in python has more NAT values

Tags: python, pandas

I am learning `Python` for Data Science. I have dataset with date column having more `NaT` values.

How to get it replaced or removed ?

Please help

Comment: use the `na_values` function while [reading](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) the file

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following check to replace or remove nat values.

```
 import numpy as np
 np.isnat(np.datetime64("NaT"))
```